# How should one prove that an account is theirs when getting a "Not a Robot" badge?

Tags: discussion, badges, not-a-robot-badge

When attending an event with at least 50 participants where Stack Overflow is the organizer or where one or more of our employees are actively participating in an event, one can earn a "Not a Robot" badge.

How is the verification happening? I heard that you should give your email address to an organizer, is that all?

Comment: Presumably the instructions are going to be specific to the event in question.   I don't see how it could be answered in the general case.

Comment: I never attended such an event, so I don't know whether that is the case.

Comment: We hand out stickers that have some sort of code on them that you enter or scan with your phone. I only know the general concept, so I'll leave an official answer for someone who has better details.

Comment: and where would we attend/find these events?

Comment: @Jason https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When there is an [event with at least 50 participants](https://stackoverflow.com/badges/get/events) that Stack Overflow is organizing or participating in we have someone (a booth or persons) who have a stack (yes, I said stack) of stickers.

The fabulous 'Not A Robot' stickers have a QR code on the back that is tied to the event it was handed out.  If you go to the website listed on the back of the sticker and enter the code (before it expires), then you will get the badge.  Yes, the codes do have expiration dates - typically they expire within a few days after the end of the event.

Comment: Wow, this is more interesting than I thought.

Comment: At least you managed "stack of stickers". Although, having said a "stick of stackers" would have been far more amusing :)

Comment: So there is no actual attempt to validate that an account referenced when using the QR code is a human? Let's say my account is called "Dharman", I go get a sticker, then I log in as my bot called, say "DharmanBot", there is nothing outside of relying on honesty?  I guess there is no way to prevent this.  And what if my grandma attends an event that I couldn't, grabs a sticker and gives it to me later that day? I mean, I didn't even attend the event.  The rules just seem super easy to abuse/circumvent